# Meteor: find objects that are created today

Tags: mongodb, date, meteor, find

I'm trying to find all Tweets (Tweets = new Meteor.Collection('tweets')) from today.

```
var today = new Date();
today.setHours(0);
today.setMinutes(0);
today.setSeconds(0);
```

Result in: Sun Nov 30 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET) - looks good. But my search query

```
Tweets.find({createdAt: {$gte: today.toISOString()}}, {sort: {createdAt: -1}})
```

still returns an empty array []. I've tried several approaches but I don't get it. What to do?

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this simple problem by myself.

```
Tweets.find({createdAt: {$gte: today}}, {sort: {createdAt: -1}})
```

For further reading: https://meteor.hackpad.com/Meteor-Cookbook-Using-Dates-and-Times-qSQCGFc06gH